# Can't install glib with cabal on Windows - during the configure step

Tags: haskell, gtk, installation, glib, cabal

On windows 7 x64, 
I tried:

```
 1. install gtk+ all in one bundle 2.16
 2. add MinGW's bin address to PATH Environment variables
 3. add GTK+'s bin address to PATH Environment variables
```

On command line execute the:

```
cabal update
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
```

So far so good. But when I execute the:

```
cabal install gtk
```

the error arise

gtk-0.12.1 depends on glib-0.12.1 which failed to install.

I execute next command:

```
cabal install glib
```

Then I tried:

```
cabal install glib --ghc-option=-DCABAL_VERSION_MINOR=10
```

Relults:

```
Resolving dependencies...

[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\glib-0.12
.16572\glib-0.12.1\SetupWrapper.hs, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\glib-0.12.1
6572\glib-0.12.1\dist\setup\SetupWrapper.o )

[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\glib-0.12
.16572\glib-0.12.1\Setup.hs, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\glib-0.12.16572\gl
ib-0.12.1\dist\setup\Main.o )

Linking C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\glib-0.12.16572\glib-0.12.1\dist\setup\
setup.exe ...

Warning: .drectve `-aligncomm:___gmp_junk,2' unrecognized

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:

glib-0.12.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\glib-0.12.16572\glib-0.12.1\dist\setup\setup.exe:

 runProcess: invalid argument (Exec format error)
```

Help, thanks!

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, but have you looked at Gtk2Hs' [install instructions](http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs/INSTALL) for Windows? A few things it mentions that you didn't: did you install in a path with spaces? Does `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` work? Did you avoid versions 2.22 and 2.16? Are you using Cabal 1.8 or later?